# Unable to download dependencies related to azure eventhubs

Tags: java

I'm working on POC related to Sending and Receiving Events with Azure Event Hub, but unable to download microsoft azure eventhubs dependencies via Maven, please could you help here.

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Still the below imports are not working.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventData;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubException;
```

Comment: According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs/2.2.0 . It is fine. Can you paste more maven error message?

Comment: Since the imports are not working, i'm unable to use the class called com.google.gson.Gson, ConnectionStringBuilder. It says cannot resolve symbol Gson, ConnectionStringBuilder. Is there a way to download the dependencies.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5  add mvn dependency as shows